# Hibernate with mysql slow when retrieving datas

Tags: java, mysql, performance, hibernate, jpa

I've a problem maybe with hibernate.

I've a request with Fetch on some collections (because i need all these datas) and the request takes 20s which is very slow for me.
the request return 92 entities 'A', for each entity 'A'-> 2 entity 'A' child and a collection of 9 entity 'B'.

I've configured my hibernate like this :

```
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm, jar"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="com.****.****.persistence.server.dialect.MyMySQLDialect" />

        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false" />

        <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3" />

        <property name="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size" value="16"/>

        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size" value="20"/> 

        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="100"/>

        <property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.order_updates" value="true"/>

        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data" value="true"/>

        <property name="org.hibernate.flushMode" value="commit"/>

        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size" value="100"/>
```

I've enabled debug log of hibernate to see what happens, and i've noticed that at some moment i lost 2-3s, and i want to know what happens there?

see :

```
08:34:47,008 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl] (EJB default - 1) Obtaining JDBC connection
08:34:47,008 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl] (EJB default - 1) Obtained JDBC connection
08:34:49,559 DEBUG [org.hibernate.loader.Loader] (EJB default - 1) Result set contains (possibly empty) collection: [com.****.****.persistence.server.entities.DataSet.****#34886]
[...]

08:34:49,642 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl] (EJB default - 1) Obtaining JDBC connection
08:34:49,642 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl] (EJB default - 1) Obtained JDBC connection
08:34:52,778 DEBUG [org.hibernate.loader.Loader] (EJB default - 1) Result set contains (possibly empty) collection: [com.****.****.persistence.server.entities.DataSet.****#32441]
[...]
08:34:52,936 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl] (EJB default - 1) Obtaining JDBC connection
08:34:52,936 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl] (EJB default - 1) Obtained JDBC connection
08:34:55,690 DEBUG [org.hibernate.loader.Loader] (EJB default - 1) Result set contains (possibly empty) collection: [com.****.****.persistence.server.entities.DataSet.****#24474]
[...]
08:34:55,830 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl] (EJB default - 1) Obtaining JDBC connection
08:34:55,830 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl] (EJB default - 1) Obtained JDBC connection
08:34:58,760 DEBUG [org.hibernate.loader.Loader] (EJB default - 1) Result set contains (possibly empty) collection: [com.****.****.persistence.server.entities.DataSet.****#21018]
```

I thought when we use FETCH JOIN, hibernate make only one request to retrieve needed data, but it seems that he makes multiples request.

Some one have an idea for what happens between these 2-3 seconds? database side?

Thanks, and sorry for my english

Comment: Try setting the     
    hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache
property to true

Check out this link https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-cache

Comment: I've configured a 2nd lvl cache using ehcache, still have the problem...

Comment: set the hibernate to print sql, you may find interesting things there

Comment: Please add your entity classes for us to check and try to create a database index for the columns used to join the A children and the B entities after fetching the A entity - a faulty/missing index can double your runtime without a problem.

Comment: Make sure you `COMMIT`.  (I see autocommit = false; this worries me.)

Comment: The commit is done at the end of session , it's not the problem, btw it's not recommended to set it to true (false is the default value).

I solved my problem by removing the property "hibernate.max_fetch_depth" i thought that concerned only explicit FETCH, but it does for lazy loading too, so for each lazy loading, hibernate was retrieving more datas than i needed.

Thanks all for your help